# XYPointerAnnotation in TimeSeries JFreeChart

Tags: java, jfreechart

I'm trying to implement `XYPointerAnnotation` to `TimeSeries` chart. However I don't know, how does chart finds my y values to plot. Code:

```
final TimeSeries series = new TimeSeries("asdfas");
Hour hour = new Hour();
series.add(2,hour), 123);
TimeSeriesCollection collection = new TimeSeriesCollection();
collection.addSeries(series);
double temp = Double.parseDouble(
    series1.getTimePeriod(series1.getItemCount()-1).toString());
XYPointerAnnotation pointer1 = new XYPointerAnnotation(
    series1.getValue(series1.getItemCount() - 1).toString(), temp, 00.0);
JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createTimeSeriesChart(
    "1", "2", "3", collection, true, true, false);
```

How can I parse y values from `TimeSeries` to the `XYPointerAnnotation`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a `TimeSeries`,

```
TimeSeries series = new TimeSeries("Data");
```

find the item of interest,

```
TimeSeriesDataItem item = series.getDataItem(series.getItemCount() - 1);
```

create an annotation based on the period and value,

```
double x = item.getPeriod().getFirstMillisecond();
double y = item.getValue().doubleValue();
XYPointerAnnotation a = new XYPointerAnnotation("Bam!", x, y, 5 * Math.PI / 8);
```

and add it to the plot,

```
XYPlot plot = (XYPlot) chart.getPlot();
plot.addAnnotation(a);
```

[image]