# setItemLabelsVisible deprecated, but setBaseItemLabelsVisible(true); does nothing

Tags: java, jfreechart, deprecated, renderer

I'm creating a JFreeChart with an `XYLineAndShapeRenderer`.

Now I want to add titles to the displayed graphs as follows:

[image]

But the method `renderer.setItemLabelsVisible(true);` seems to be deprecated:

[image]

Now I have tried doing the following:

```
    renderer.setBaseItemLabelGenerator(new StandardXYItemLabelGenerator());
    renderer.setBaseItemLabelsVisible(true);
```

But no result showed up.

Then I tried

```
renderer.setSeriesItemLabelsVisible(2, true);
```

But this also yields no result.

So my question is:

**What is the correct alternative for** `renderer.setItemLabelsVisible(true);`**?**

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for one of the [`setBaseItemLabelsVisible()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/AbstractRenderer.html#setBaseItemLabelsVisible%28boolean%29) implementations, suggested in the [API](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/AbstractRenderer.html#setItemLabelsVisible%28boolean%29). There are examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14459322/230513) and [here](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/jfreechartdemo).

Addendum: For individual labels, consider a suitable annotation, seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18328489/230513) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18194728/230513).

Comment: As the examples cited work using `setBaseItemLabelGenerator()`, I'm guessing something else is wrong; please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits the problem you describe.

Answer (score -1):

```
final IntervalMarker target = new IntervalMarker(4.5,5.0);target.setLabel("30 day moving average");
target.setLabelPaint(Color.RED);
target.setLabelAnchor(RectangleAnchor.LEFT);
target.setLabelTextAnchor(TextAnchor.TOP_LEFT);target.setPaint(Color.RED);
plot.addRangeMarker(target, Layer.BACKGROUND);
```